# How to restrict an attribute of an extended type

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to derive elements from a base type. This base type (let's call it Entity) has an id attribute. For derived elements I want to add restrictions to this attribute (different restrictions for different derived Entity elements):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="Entity">
        <xs:attribute name="id">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]+[0-9]+"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="someEntity">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="Entity">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="someAdditionalElement"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <!-- I would like to restrict the attribute "id" for this entity to e.g. the pattern "SOME[0-9]+" -->
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="otherEntity">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="Entity">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="otherAdditionalElement"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <!-- I would like to restrict the attribute "id" for this entity to a differtnt pattern like e.g. "OTHER[0-9]+" -->
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly add elements to the type Entity when extending the type; you can certainly restrict the id attribute when restricting the type.  The only things you cannot do, of what you describe, are (1) extend and restrict a type at the same time, and (2) 'restrict' an id attribute which accepts only uppercase alphabetic strings by allowing it to accept strings containing decimal digits as well.  (Those may be what MiMo had in mind when he said you couldn't do what you want to do.)

So the way to do what you want is:

1. Define the complex type Entity, with an id attribute that allows all the forms of id you want to allow on derived types.
2. For each derived type (in your example, someEntity and otherEntity), derive first a restriction of Entity, and then an extension of that restriction -- or vice versa, first an extension and then a restriction.  If you don't want these intermediate types to be used for any elements elsewhere, then make them abstract.

When you restrict the type of an attribute (here, the id attribute), the XSD validator needs to be able to see easily that the new type is a restriction of the old one.  So you don't want to use a locally defined type for Entity's id attribute; you want a defined type.  So you'll want to replace your declaration for Entity with two declarations, something like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="uppercase-alphanumeric-string">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9]+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="Entity">
  <xs:attribute name="id" type="uppercase-alphanumeric-string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Then you can define the type of your element someEntity in two steps.  First, define a complex type with an appropriate restriction of the Entity type:

```
<xs:complexType name="Entity-restriction-SOME" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="Entity">
      <xs:attribute name="id">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="uppercase-alphanumeric-string">
            <xs:pattern value="SOME[0-9]+"></xs:pattern>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

As noted above, you can do either restriction then extension, or extension then restriction. I'm doing the restriction first to avoid having to re-specify the content model for the extended type.

Then you can specify the extension of the restriction in the usual way:

```
<xs:element name="someEntity">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Entity-restriction-SOME">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="someAdditionalElement"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'll leave otherElement as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The restriction pattern for the type Entity was incomplete ([A-Z]+) - was intended to be [A-Z]+[0-9]+ or [A-Z0-9]. I corrected this now.
Thanks for the comprehensive and helpful answer.